# Reading file from External Storage

Tags: android, readfile, fileinputstream, android-external-storage

[Docs](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fguide%2Ftopics%2Fdata%2Fdata-storage.html&ei=T5iXVcCJI4uqU4iCpIgB&usg=AFQjCNGp43XUcnNOhRE7DytXA07IG44RHw&sig2=Pr0XyTBsHclhclkrwpBvfg&bvm=bv.96952980,d.d24) say:

> In order to read or write files on the external storage, your app must
>   acquire the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE system
>   permissions.

I do not use `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions in manifest of my App. But it is strange, because this code runs successfully:

```
File file = new File("/storage/sdcard0/ImageStore/Mat1.jpg");
FileInputStream fis = null;
byte[] buffer = null;
try {
    fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    buffer = new byte[1024];
    fis.read(buffer );
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Why this code runs without exception while reading and writing  permissions are denied?

Note:

If External Storage is not mounted,bad mounted or ..., then obviously `FileNotFoundException` occurs

Comment: What if sdcard0 is internal storage?

Comment: @Blackbelt OK! if sdcard is not mounted, then obviously `FileNotFound` occurs.

Comment: where are you testing the code ? I mean on what version of android ?

Comment: @Blackbelt I test code on android emulators (android 2.3.3) and real device(android 4.1.1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

developer.android.com states this regarding the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

> This permission is enforced starting in API level 19. Before API level 19, this permission is not enforced and all apps still have access to read from external storage.

Answer (score 4):

`READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` was introduced on API Level 16 and enforced in Api level 19 (KITKAT). Before it there was no special permission to read from the external storage but only to write in it. From the documentation

> This permission is enforced starting in API level 19. Before API level
>   19, this permission is not enforced and all apps still have access to
>   read from external storage.